# ToListAsync() - SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao tentar listar todos os registros de um modelo:

> SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be
>   called on Null values.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()

Meu método:

```
//GET: api/empresa
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Empresa>>> getEmpresas()
{
    return await _context.Empresas.ToListAsync();
}
```

Meu modelo:

```
public class Empresa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    public string Complemento { get; set; }
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Localidade { get; set; }
    public string UF { get; set; }
    public int Unidade { get; set; }
    public int IBGE { get; set; }
    public int GIA { get; set; }
    public string Telefone{get;set;}
}
```

No meu bd esta são as colunas e o resultado da seleção de todos os registros:

Pelo que pesquisei esse erro acontece quando tem uma coluna não nulo no bd, porém nesse caso apenas o Id (chave primária) é não-nulo, porém ela já é auto-incrementada.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O erro que está ocorrendo de `get_Int32` deve ser por que um campo `int` na tabela Empresa é `null` e na classe `Empresa` nenhuma propriedade `int` está como null.

Tente colocar `int? Numero`, `int? Unidade` e assim por diante.

Comment: o miserável é um gênio